# Can't pass $db as global variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am wondering why I cannot do this in PHP.

**DB.PHP**

```
function db_connect(){
    try {
        $db = new PDO('xxxxxxxx');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $db;
}
```

**FUNCTION.PHP**

```
require_once('db.php');
$db = db_connect();

//Incoming AJAX request

if(isset($_POST['rowId'])) $rowId = $_POST['rowId'];
if(isset($_POST['func'])){
    $func = $_POST['func'];
    switch($func){  
        case "info":
            echo json_encode(info($rowId));
        break;
    }
}

function info($rowId){
  global $db;
  $rowInfo = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = :rowId");
  $rowInfo->bindParam(':rowId', $rowId);
  $rowInfo->execute();
//do more stuff
```

I get this error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string

I can solve it two ways

1. Don't use any bound params (which is obviously useless here)
2. Pass `$db` into the function

What is the problem ? The error occurs on execte(). I can remove anything after itand still get th error.

Comment: You need to also assign `$db` in the global scope. Nothing in your excerpts does assert that this is where `functions.php` was included.

Comment: @mario He has `$db = db_connect();`, that assigns it in the global scope.

Comment: The error message indicates that the variable IS set to a PDO object, but you're using it in a place where a string is required, like `echo $db;`. What's on the line that's getting that error?

Comment: @mario I'm assuming the code is as he shows it, the assignment is at top-level in the `function.php` script.

Comment: What are you returning from the info function.  The error seems like it is returning the pdo $rowInfo object and then trying to encode that to a json string.  Pull out the info($rowId) into a seperate line and have a look at what is coming back from that.

Comment: Pretty useless exception handling in your `db_connect()` function. If the connection fails, you're still returning `$db` which would be `null`. Also, where is the rest of the error message? Which line of which file causes the error?

Comment: @Tester You mention `//do more stuff`
you have to make sure you return $rowInfo->fetch() and nothing else.
somehwere in your code you are doing converting the pdo object as a string for examplestrval($rowInfo) you will get the Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string error.

Comment: I put //dostuff  because it doesn't matter what comes after there (I can cut out everything). The error occurs on the execute()

Answer (score 0):

So $rowID contains an object.

The execute function attempts to convert the Message object to a string but finds that there is not __toString function declared.

So either declare

```
public function __toString() {
   return $the_string;
}
```

or create another public function/member that you can pass to the execute function.

Comment: But why am I able to resolve this by passing $db into the function as a param?

Comment: Furthermore I have never had any issues with passing a $_POST var. It is a string already or at least it is accepted as one.